# Sending GET query using Javascript to GAE to redirect to another page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, get

On GAE (Python) I'm trying to send a GET request from local javascript and on receipt of the request redirect to another page. This is my code:

Local Javascript sending the POST:

```
$.get("/editor");
```

The Python on GAE

```py
class Editor(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', StartScreen), ('/editor', Editor)],
                              debug=True)
```

I can type in the url /editor in the url bar and it does take me there. Why does my javascript GET request not activate the Editor handler and open /editor?

Comment: What happens to the request? Do you get an error? Does your code redirect before the page successfully responds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the problem, but still give it a try:
The current way to use `jQuery.get()` should call the server but throw away the response, so you will see nothing of it in the browser.
You want at least to do:

```
$.get("/editor", function(response) { 
     document.location.href = 'another page'; 
});
```

where `another page` is where you want to redirect to. Then this still throws away what you content you get from the server. (`response` will be some HTML ... I am not sure how you want to get a location from that.) So I wonder if a simple HTML-link would just do what you want.